# Projected area of a paralelogram over a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u=\hat{i} +\hat{j} +\hat{k}$  and  $v=\hat { i } - \hat { j } -\hat { k }$ two vectors that are the two coterminal sides of a paralelogram. Compute the projected area by this paralelogram over the plane whose unit normal vector is $n=\hat {i} + 2\dfrac{\hat {j}}{3} +2\dfrac{\hat {k}}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection of $u$ onto the plane is $u - \hat{n}\hat{n}^Tu$ and similarly for $v$. Once you have the two projected sides, take the magnitude of their cross product to get the parallelogram area.

Where are you getting stuck?